# JSON value not converted to System.Boolean in cURL

Tags: api, asp.net-core, jsonconverter

I created Boolean converter expecting it would be used automatically on the property IsComplete, but get an error in cURL. What am I doing wrong?

Error

```
$ curl -k -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"momo\", \"isComplete\":\"true\"}" https://localhost:44358/api/TodoItems/PutItem?id=2
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|f2fadf22-471bc26be11d1bad.","errors":{"$.isComplete":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.isComplete | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 36."]}}
```

Converter

```
namespace System.Text.Json.Serialization
{
    public class BooleanConverter : JsonConverter<bool>
    {

        public override bool Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            bool.Parse(reader.GetString());

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            bool b,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(b.ToString());
    }
}
```

Attributes

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created Boolean converter expecting it would be used automatically on the property IsComplete

You can try to register your custom converter on `IsComplete` property of your `TodoItem` class.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(BooleanConverter))]
public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
```

For more information about "register a custom converter ", please check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#register-a-custom-converter